# Mid-2012 MacBook Pro is unable to connect with external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I want to connect an external monitor (HP E230t) to my MacBook Pro (A1278). I am using a Thunderbolt-to-HDMI connector. When I plug in the connector, the MBP's screen goes down for 1-2 seconds but then monitor the indicates it does not detect any input. How can I connect this monitor to my MBP or what can I further do to identify the underlying problem?

According to various sources:

1. When the connector is plugged or unplugged, the MBP screen is to go down for 1-2 sec (checked).
2. External monitor needs to be fully functional (checked).

Comment: Are you sure the connector is also fully functional?

Comment: Lose the HDMI and use DisplayPort.

Comment: Check if you can change the HDMI Version on the Monitor OSD and try a different option if you can.